# Key Gesture for any combination of integer after CTRL

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using key gestures in C# as hot keys for my application 
I know how to do <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>

```
new KeyGesture(Key.S, ModifierKeys.Shift | ModifierKeys.Control)
```

but can any body tell me how to get gesture for <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>+<kbd>(any integer from 1 t0 50)</kbd>?

Answer (score 1):

A simple `KeyGesture` wont allow you to do multiple-key strokes but you could extend the `KeyGesture` class to support this. Now the numbers 0 to 9 are easy but above that gets complicated as what you need to take into conderideration is numbers above 9 become two key stokes (essentially 3 including the <kbd>e</kbd> character).

Here is a sample class that allows for multiple key bindings (note I didnt write this and cant remeber where I got it from).

KeyGesture Class:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(MultiKeyGestureConverter))]
public class MultiKeyGesture : KeyGesture
{
    private readonly IList<Key> _keys;
    private readonly ReadOnlyCollection<Key> _readOnlyKeys;
    private int _currentKeyIndex;
    private DateTime _lastKeyPress;
    private static readonly TimeSpan _maximumDelayBetweenKeyPresses = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);

    public MultiKeyGesture(IEnumerable<Key> keys, ModifierKeys modifiers)
        : this(keys, modifiers, string.Empty)
    {
    }

    public MultiKeyGesture(IEnumerable<Key> keys, ModifierKeys modifiers, string displayString)
        : base(Key.None, modifiers, displayString)
    {
        _keys = new List<Key>(keys);
        _readOnlyKeys = new ReadOnlyCollection<Key>(_keys);

        if (_keys.Count == 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("At least one key must be specified.", "keys");
        }
    }

    public ICollection<Key> Keys
    {
        get { return _readOnlyKeys; }
    }

    public override bool Matches(object targetElement, InputEventArgs inputEventArgs)
    {
        var args = inputEventArgs as KeyEventArgs;

        if ((args == null) || !IsDefinedKey(args.Key))
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (_currentKeyIndex != 0 && ((DateTime.Now - _lastKeyPress) > _maximumDelayBetweenKeyPresses))
        {
            //took too long to press next key so reset
            _currentKeyIndex = 0;
            return false;
        }

        //the modifier only needs to be held down for the first keystroke, but you could also require that the modifier be held down for every keystroke
        if (_currentKeyIndex == 0 && Modifiers != Keyboard.Modifiers)
        {
            //wrong modifiers
            _currentKeyIndex = 0;
            return false;
        }

        if (_keys[_currentKeyIndex] != args.Key)
        {
            //wrong key
            _currentKeyIndex = 0;
            return false;
        }

        ++_currentKeyIndex;

        if (_currentKeyIndex != _keys.Count)
        {
            //still matching
            _lastKeyPress = DateTime.Now;
            inputEventArgs.Handled = true;
            return false;
        }

        //match complete
        _currentKeyIndex = 0;
        return true;
    }

    private static bool IsDefinedKey(Key key)
    {
        return ((key >= Key.None) && (key <= Key.OemClear));
    }
}
```

Type Converter:

```
public class MultiKeyGestureConverter : TypeConverter
{
    private readonly KeyConverter _keyConverter;
    private readonly ModifierKeysConverter _modifierKeysConverter;

    public MultiKeyGestureConverter()
    {
        _keyConverter = new KeyConverter();
        _modifierKeysConverter = new ModifierKeysConverter();
    }

    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        return sourceType == typeof(string);
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        var keyStrokes = (value as string).Split(',');
        var firstKeyStroke = keyStrokes[0];
        var firstKeyStrokeParts = firstKeyStroke.Split('+');

        var modifierKeys = (ModifierKeys)_modifierKeysConverter.ConvertFrom(firstKeyStrokeParts[0]);
        var keys = new List<Key>();

        keys.Add((Key)_keyConverter.ConvertFrom(firstKeyStrokeParts[1]));

        for (var i = 1; i < keyStrokes.Length; ++i)
        {
            keys.Add((Key)_keyConverter.ConvertFrom(keyStrokes[i]));
        }

        return new MultiKeyGesture(keys, modifierKeys);
    }
}
```

Now this class is simple, it allows multiple keys to be bound with attached modifiers. This could then be used as.

`this.InputBindings.Add(new InputBinding(MyCommand, new MultiKeyGesture(new Key[] { Key.E, Key.D1 }, ModifierKeys.Control, "Ctrl+E, 1")));`

This binds the command `MyCommand` to the key commands <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>

Now this is simple to bind the numbers <kbd>0</kbd> to <kbd>9</kbd> however going above you may run into issues when the users has to enter two numbers such as 10 would be: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd>

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for